# Can I add an SWT Canvas to Shell

Tags: java, canvas, swt, awt

I made a project using AWT. For this project I have 2 panels. One panel with a bunch of JComponents and another with just a Canvas (AWT). I am in the process of converting the project from AWT over to SWT. I already fixed my Class that extends my AWT Canvas so that it extends an SWT Canvas and updated appropriate methods inside. I am confused on how I would add this Canvas to a Shell seeing how there is no `add()` method. Any info on how to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you need to go through an SWT tutorial such as [this one](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/SWT/article.html). You always specify the parent of a SWT control in the first argument of the constructor.

Comment: you should use AWT_SWT Bridge class